# Is it true that measurable functions that differ only in a null measure set are in the same class?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Is it true that measurable functions that differ only in a null measure set are in the same class? I'm thinking about this and I can't get arguments.

If the answer is yes, can you give me an example that compares the norms in $L_p$ and $L_\infty$ of two functions that differ by a null measure set?

Comment: Yes, functions that are equal almost everywhere are thought as the same function in many contexts. That is because the integral of both functions are the same, and for example in $L_p$ the norm is the same because the norm is defined as an integral.

Comment: @Marcos But what about $L_\infty$?

Comment: $L_\infty$ is defined in a special way with the essencial supremum to solve this problem. Maybe you've never seen the rigurous construction of $L_\infty$, but if you do, you'll see why there is no distinction between sets of measure $0$.

Comment: @Marcos Hmmm, ok. Do you know an easy example that I can see this fact? Two easy measurable functions that differ in a null measure set. I just wanna visualize this fact with a simple example. :)

Comment: The key idea is that if $f,g$ differ only on a set of zero measure, then $|f-g|$ is zero almost everywhere, and the same for $|f-g|^p$.  So its integral is zero, which addresses $L^p$, $p < \infty$.  For $L^\infty$, prove as an exercise that if $h=0$ almost everywhere, then $\|h\|_{L^\infty} = 0$, and apply this to $h = |f-g|$.

Comment: Simple example: $f(x) \equiv 1$, $g(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \ne 0 \\ 42, & x =0 \end{cases}$

Comment: Yeah, that's easy. For example you can take $f=0$ and $g(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks! Let's see:
Let $L_\infty(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be the set of all measurable functions that are bounded $\mu$-almost always, that is, there is a set $A \in \Sigma$ and a real number $K$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$ and $|f(x)| \leq K$ for all $x \not\in A$. Then
$$||h||_\infty=\inf\{\sup\{|h(x)|;x\not\in A\};A\in\Sigma\text{ and }\mu(A)=0\}.$$
How can I use the fact that $h=0$ almost everywhere in this norm?

Comment: @Marcos Thanks! I got it with those examples.

Comment: @Manatee: Take $A = \{x : h(x) \ne 0\}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge So it look that $\sup\{|h(x)|;x\not\in A\}=0$, am I right? Then the $\inf$ is obviosly zero.

Comment: @Manatee: Yes, right.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah!!!